# Ruby or Bash or Grep regex is not working for '?' i.e. 0 or 1 occurrence of previous character

Tags: ruby, regex, linux, bash, grep

**Linux** Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)

**Issue:**
I have 2 Jenkins jobs and they both which calls another common/reusable downstream job (that uses a regex to pick its rpm). Actual code is written in Ruby (where I was using `::Dir.glob("<pattern>",'')` and it didn't work for picking the correct rpm name (without giving me any error), but here I'm just focusing on the regex part.

In **job1**, in my workspace, I see `myrpm.rpm` and `myrpm-extra.rpm`.

In **job2**, in my workspace, I see `myrpm-3.0.0.1027-2018_12_21_121519.noarch.rpm` and `myrpm-extra-3.0.0.1027-2018_12_21_121519.noarch.rpm` rpms which I'm getting after downloading these files from Artifactory via some AQL.

Once rpms are downloaded from Aritfactory i.e. available in Jenkins workspace , then I use this common downstream job to pick a given rpm that I need by
using `"${rpmname}*.rpm"` regex.

The issue is, when I'm passing `rpmname` parameter value as "**myrpm**", the logic is picking `myrpm-extra.rpm` (in ***Job1***) or `myrpm-extra-3.0.0.1027-2018_12_21_121519.noarch.rpm` (***Job2***) instead of the correct one (non extra one), as `-` character's order comes first due to ASCII sequence.

I tested the regex and seeing why in the last command I didn't see expected output. Isn't `1?` in the regex going to give us any lines which has `arun` with either `0 or 1` occurrence of character `1`?

```
[giga@linux-server giga]# echo -e "arun\narun1\narun2\narun11" |grep "arun"
arun
arun1
arun2
arun11
[giga@linux-server giga]#

[giga@linux-server giga]# echo -e "arun\narun1\narun2\narun11" |grep "arun1"
arun1
arun11
[giga@linux-server giga]#

[giga@linux-server giga]# echo -e "arun\narun1\narun2\narun11" |grep "arun1?"
[giga@linux-server giga]#
```

**Questions:**
1. Why this works if I use `egrep`?
2. Why it didn't work with `grep`, while `grep` man page / examples tells it supports it?
3. What regex can I use so that if I pass `myrpm` as the job parameter's value, then it works in both Job1 and Job2 where rpm filename contains either the short and full rpm name.

Here: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/ (search for **grep Regular Expression Operator**) and

`man grep` shows:

```
   Repetition
       A regular expression may be followed by one of several repetition operators:
       ---------------------------------------------------------------
       ?      The preceding item is optional and matched at most once.
       ---------------------------------------------------------------  
       *      The preceding item will be matched zero or more times.
       +      The preceding item will be matched one or more times.
       {n}    The preceding item is matched exactly n times.
       {n,}   The preceding item is matched n or more times.
       {,m}   The preceding item is matched at most m times.  This is a GNU extension.
       {n,m}  The preceding item is matched at least n times, but not more than m times.
```

Comment: `grep -E "arun1?"` uses extended regex. `?` in BRE is just a literal `?`

Comment: The pertinent line from the man page: `In  basic regular expressions the metacharacters ?, +, {, |, (, and ) lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions \?, \+, \{, \|, \(, and \).`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava Is there any expression that can work for both Job1 and Job2 case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`egrep` is the same as `grep -E`, in your case, the `regex` used, need `-E` or `-P` to support `?`.

Search for different `regex` support please.  There're `POSIX`, `Extended`, and `Perl` etc.

Resources:
[POSIX Basic and Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html)
[Perl regular expressions](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[Regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

Comment: Thanks @Tiw, I think I got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Final** Solution:
Used this regex pattern: `${package_name}(?:-[0-9]*)?\..*rpm`, example of code (in Ruby) is shown below.

In Ruby: after you change to the directory where the rpms existed, I got this line to find the correct rpm name. **NOTE:** In Ruby, `::Dir.glob("<pattern>",..)` is [not a real REGEX pattern](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Dir.html#method-c-glob), it's just a SHELL glob pattern.

```
  wildcard = "#{new_resource.session['package_name']}(?:-[0-9]*)?\..*#{ext_type}"
rpmfullname = Dir["#{new_resource.session['package_name']}*.#{ext_type}"].select { |f| f =~ /#{wildcard}/ }.sort.first
```

This website greatly helped.
https://rubular.com/ 
with example pattern being `myrpm(?:-[0-9]*)?\..*rpm`: 
and test cases strings as:

```
myrpm.rpm
myrpm-extra.rpm
myrpm-1.0.0_112233.noarch.rpm
myrpm-11.0.0_112233.noarch.rpm
myrpm-111.0.0_112233.noarch.rpm
myrpm-1.0_112233.noarch.rpm
myrpm-extra-1.0.0_112233.noarch.rpm
foo.yum
berayan.rpm
arun.yum
Toni.rpm
myrpm-1.0.0_112233.rpm
```